How to derive the average current drawn by the op amp in the given circuit?
For the circuit, I have calculated the output current to be (pi/20)*cos(wt) and the average of this is 0. But, since the initial conditions tell Ip= Im= 3mA, I thought the average current will turn out to be 3mA. But the answer is 53mA. Where did I go wrong?


Any energy that's dissipated in the load resistors must necessarily come from the OpAmp's supply pins. The OpAmp can't magically take energy from nowhere.
The OpAmp acts as a kind of (reverse) rectifier. Whenever it sources ("pushes") current from its output into the load, it takes this current from the positive supply rail. Similarly, when the OpAmp sinks ("pulls") current from the output, it does so via the negative supply pin.
In other words: Whenever the output current is positive, it comes from Ip. Whenever it's negative, it comes from Im.
This means that while the output current averages out to zero, the currents Ip and Im do not. You need to average only the positive parts of the output current waveform to get Ip, and only the negative parts to get Im. (And then add the OpAmp's quiescent current, which you mentioned to be 3mA.)


The gain is two and the input peak voltage is \$\pi\$
Therefore the output voltage peak is \$2\pi\$ volts
The average voltage of a positive half cycle is peak divided by \$\pi\$ = 2 volts
The average load/feedback current is therefore 2/(200||50) = 2/40 = 50 mA
The same is true of the negative half cycles of the signal but, because of two negatives in the calculation, the current is equivalent to a positive current from the positive supply
Hence the average supply current feeding the feedback and load is 50 mA
The 3 mA current adds to this making 53 mA in total


@internet oops I meant 200 not 100... correcting
